# Accessing /proc from foreign chroot

Tags: mount, qemu, chroot, proc

I am trying to set up a foreign chroot environment with QEMU, mostly as described at https://www.hellion.org.uk/blog/posts/foreign-chroots-with-schroot-and-qemu/.

The host system is Ubuntu x86_64 (on Github Actions), the foreign chroot runs Debian for arm.

Now I am trying to set up OCaml by installing `opam` via apt, then running `opam init`. That fails because `/proc/sys/kernel/overflowuid` is not found.

Digging a bit deeper, I found `/proc` inside the chroot jail is completely empty. I tried adding `sudo mount -B /proc $CROSS_ROOT/proc` to the script right after running `debootstrap`, still to no avail – `/proc` is still empty. Same with `sudo mount -t proc /proc $CROSS_ROOT/proc`.

Also, when I run `mount | grep proc` outside the chroot jail, I see `/proc` but not `CROSS_ROOT/proc`.

Another oddity I notice is that when I run `mount` inside the chroot jail to list mounts, I get an error saying `mtab` was not found – is that normal, or does that indicate something else is wrong here?

To rule out trivial errors – I use `$CROSS_ROOT` multiple times in my CI script, also in the call to `debootstrap`. If that var were empty, I suppose I’d be having a bunch of other errors.

Why am I not seeing `/proc` inside my chroot jail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debootstrap` runs in two stages:

```
sudo debootstrap --variant=buildd --include=fakeroot,build-essential,sudo --arch=armhf --foreign buster $CROSS_ROOT $CROSS_MIRROR
sudo chroot $CROSS_ROOT ./debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

Mounting `/proc` must be done after the second stage, not between the two stages – the second stage will unmount `/proc` again. (The source mentioned in the question does some extra magic to provide `qemu-arm-static` inside the chroot, which must indeed happen between the two stages. Any other customizations to the file system, especially of the kind that involve central system components, may break things or get undone by the second stage.)

After moving the mount commands behind the second stage of `debootstrap`, my chroot jail is seeing `/proc`.